# NLP Matching city names and returning relative match score

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have a use case where I need to extract real estate property name, city and state (if it is available) in news headline and match against records available in database. I am able to extract entities from news headline using open source NLP statistical model in python but facing issue while matching city name against db record city names.

For example matching extracted city name "N York" from news headline against a DB row with city name "New York".

I tried multiple python libraries like Fuzzy Wuzzy, Levenshtein distance, Spacy similarity function but doesn't seems to fit in my use case.

I need some direction on how to achieve city name matching and generating relative match score.

Comment: Please explain how you tried these multiple libraries and why their results don't satisfy you - then someone could come up with an idea what to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Before seeing your data, it seems to me that you need to use one or another version of edit distance - if not Levenshtein, then maybe Jaro Winkler, or any other distance fucntion from https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/ . Or maybe even a weighted average of multiple distance functions.

And if you give more examples of difficult city name pairs, it would be easier to come up with more specific advice. E.g. JW distance between N York and New York is 0.925 - what's exactly wrong with this number?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for achieving city name matching is using a better location database. I **highly** recommend that you check out [www.GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org).

They provide a truly massive database of locations. In addition to their tables for cities, countries, etc. They also provide an AlternateNames table with aliases. So, for example, "Big Apple" and "NYC" are connected to "New York City" via a foreign key.

Other than really obscure references like "N York", this will satisfy your requirements for sure. And since your source is news headlines, I think the spelling etc will be pretty well conserved.

You can find all the data here:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

And it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Use phonetics, it creates phonetic key for each speech sound,

```
phonetics.dmetaphone('New York')
phonetics.dmetaphone('N York')
```

above both give you unique phonetic key

[Reference](https://pypi.org/project/phonetics/)